# Selecting rows within last 30 days

Tags: abap, opensql

I've got a select statement to get the orders of a reference, but now I need to restrict the results into a range od the last 30 days but i don't know how to do it.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM AFKO
WHERE AFKO~PLNBEZ = @reference
AND DATEDIFF( DAY, AFKO~GLTRP, @sy-datum ) >= -30
ORDER BY AFKO~GLTRP DESCENDING
INTO TABLE @it_afko.
```

I've readed that DATEDIFF can make the operatio but SAP says that the function is unknown.
I'm trying directly using the - operator:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM AFKO
WHERE AFKO~PLNBEZ = @reference
AND AFKO~GLTRP - @sy-datum >= -30
ORDER BY AFKO~GLTRP DESCENDING
INTO TABLE @it_afko.
```

but SAP says Only elementary arithmetic types can be used in arithmetic expressions. The type of AFKO~GLTRP is invalid

How can I get the difference?

Comment: The ABAP documentation of Open SQL doesn't show `DATEDIFF` in the list of possible functions, where did you get that? Why don't you calculate a variable equal to `SY-DATUM` minus 30 days and just compare it? Or even just doing it with a [host expression](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenopen_sql_host_expressions.htm) like `AFKO~GLTRP >= @( sy-datum - 30 )` (since 7.50) ? Or use one of the possible [date functions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_date_func.htm) (since 7.51) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a field and calculate the date accordingly:

```
DATA(lv_date_minus_30) = sy-datum - 30.

SELECT ...
       WHERE ... gltrp >= lv_date_minus_30
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare calculated date before using it in opensql for old versions like below example.

```
DATA: lv_date   TYPE sy-datum,
      reference TYPE afko-plnbez,
      it_afko   TYPE TABLE OF afko.

CALL FUNCTION 'RP_CALC_DATE_IN_INTERVAL'
  EXPORTING
    date            = sy-datum
    days            = 30
    months          = 0
    signum          = '-'
    years           = 0
 IMPORTING
   calc_date       = lv_date.

SELECT *
  FROM afko
  INTO TABLE @it_afko
 WHERE afko~plnbez = @reference
   AND afko~gltrp >= @lv_date
 ORDER BY afko~gltrp DESCENDING.
```